# Get the file correctly after uploading with md5

Tags: php, hash, upload, opencart, md5

The following is part of the code in upload.php of [OpenCart](http://www.opencart.com/):

```
    $file = $filename . '.' . md5(mt_rand());

    move_uploaded_file($this->request->files['file']['tmp_name'], DIR_UPLOAD . $file);

    // Hide the uploaded file name so people can not link to it directly.
    $this->load->model('tool/upload');

    $json['code'] = $this->model_tool_upload->addUpload($filename, $file);
```

For the coding `'$this->model_tool_upload->addUpload($filename, $file)'`, it will insert the data like this:

[image]

The field 'code' is generated by the the coding `'sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true))'`.

And the new file will inserted into the folder:

[image]

I would like to upload image and then display it. In this situation, how can I get the file path correctly using PHP?

Also, can someone explain why the filename is appended with the md5 string? Is it only used for hide the uploaded file name and what is the field 'code' used for?

**UPDATE**

Just find the answer in one of the source file:

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . ($mask ? $mask : basename($file)) . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
readfile($file, 'rb');
```

Comment: `$file = $filename . '.' . md5(mt_rand());` should be `$file =  md5(mt_rand()) . '.' . $filename;`